# Put the data from firestore into next php file

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have several values in cloud firestore and want to access every variables. Hence I do my code like this

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$db = new FirestoreClient(
    [
        'projectId' => 'fakedata-aa798'
    ]
);

$collectionReference = $db->collection('Test3');
$docRef = $collectionReference->document('User1');
$snapshot = $docRef->snapshot();

$Name= $snapshot['Name'];
$Contact= $snapshot['Contact no:'];
$Email= $snapshot['Email'];
$Location= $snapshot['Location'];
$Locationstatus= $snapshot['Location status'];
$Condition= $snapshot['Condition'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['Name'] = $Name;
$_SESSION['Contact no:'] = $Contact;
$_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
$_SESSION['Location'] = $Location;
$_SESSION['Location status'] = $Locationstatus;
$_SESSION['Condition'] = $Condition;
?>
```

Now I want to display the values in next PHP files and I use session_start but still can't get the values

pages2

```
<?php
session_start();
                                        
echo $_SESSION['Name']; 
?>
```

Can someone help me?